# Importing/Exporting Sql Server 2008 database into MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, mysqlimport

I have a relatively large database in SQL Server 2008R2 that I need to export to MySql. I tried the "Import and Export Data" option for SQL Server but it provides no option for exporting to MySQL

Please assist with the possible way on how to achieve this.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619177/sql-server-2008-r2-to-mysql-migration/12948473#12948473

Comment: If you have completed migration successfuly then please post your answer here.

Answer (score 0):

There's an open source application at sourceforge named [MSSQL2MySQL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mssql2mysql/) that might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If I was you. I would have gone for [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/)

Its a brilliant software and a very simple UI to import and export data within different types of server

Cheers!!